# PyQt: How to move widgets inside QStackedWidget object?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've created window with button named "First", the window shows me next button named "Second" after clicking on the button "First", but button "Second" isn't moved by:

```
self.b2.move(50,50)
```

Whats the problem?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):

       super().__init__()
       self.init_UI()

   def init_UI(self):

       self.Centr= QtWidgets.QWidget()
       self.setCentralWidget(self.Centr)

       self.window = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.Centr)
       self.b1 = self.addButton()
       self.window.addWidget(self.b1)
       self.b2 = self.addButton_2()
       self.b2.move(50,50)
       self.window.addWidget(self.b2)

       self.b1.clicked.connect(self.b1_clk)

       self.currentStack(0)

       self.show()

   def addButton(self): 
       b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("First")
       return b1

   def addButton_2(self):  
       b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Second")
       return b2

   def b1_clk(self):
       self.currentStack(1)

   def currentStack(self, index):
      self.window.setCurrentIndex(index)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry for my English.
And thank you for your attention!

Comment: Why do you want to place a button in the QStackedWidget? It is normal to place it inside the pages managed by the QStackedWidget.

Comment: In other words: add buttons to a widget, then add this widget  to the stack.

Comment: @eyllanesc okey! thank you! Using PyQt for the first time.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button *is* moved, but then it's immediately added to the `QStackedWidget`, which will change the parenting and undo the move.  Plus, with a `QStackedWidget`, the child widgets size and position are controlled by the size and position of the `QStackedWidget`

Comment: Thank you! But how can I move button in window? I'm trying by `self.window.b2.move(50,50)` after adding button into window widget and catch: _'QStackedWidget' object has no attribute 'b2'_

Comment: Will it better tactic to add all buttons in different _CentralWidget_, then add all _CentralWidget_ in _QStackedWidget_ and managing its by _QStackedWidget_ methods?

Comment: @ArtemGetmanskiy You generally shouldn't be using the move command.  Very few widgets are hard positioned.  People generally use `QLayouts` and spacers to position their widgets.  You should probably add a `QWidget` to the stacked widget and position the button inside that with a layout and some spacer items.

Comment: Also, if you find the answer helpful, you should generally upvote.